# Kendo layout breaks when disabling wrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, single-page-application

In Kendo Views, you can disabled the content being wrapped in a  by feeding it the option `{ wrap: false }`. This is documented here: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/view#configuration-wrap

However, this option breaks Kendo layout when initialized with it. My understanding is the Kendo layout inherits view, so it should work the same way?

```
var layout = new kendo.Layout('<div id="body"></div>', { wrap: false });
layout.render("#main");
layout.showIn("#body", new kendo.View("<p>This is content</p>"));
```

There isn't any error message, just a blank screen. Removing the wrap option from the layout init works again, but I am trying to disable wrapping the layout with a dummy div.

http://jsfiddle.net/5SWYu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap set to false relies that the template will have a single root element. I just updated [the documentation](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-docs/commit/550452053cc9304f3500ad6af07e9bfebd5e02b5) to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

`wrap` is a configuration parameter of `View` not of `Layout`. Your code should read:

```
var layout = new kendo.Layout('<div id="body"></div>');
layout.render("#main");
layout.showIn("#body", new kendo.View("<p>This is content</p>", { wrap: false }));
```

This is your JSFiddle modified : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/5SWYu/1/